# What are some words and/or phrases to describe devaluing and overvaluing something?

Tags: idioms, vocabulary, phrases, synonyms, antonyms

What words or phrases are used to describe the following?

- to cause the value of something to go higher than it's actually worth because you paid for it more because you're rich and don't care
- to cause the value of something to go lower because you offered it at a lower price than it's supposed to be worth because you're desperate

Answer (score 2):

You can talking about "pushing prices up" or "down".

> ...[The rich are] paying a premium for properties near good schools, pushing house prices up.

Selling at an artificially low price is called "discounting".  An item that is sold at a very low price to attract customers who might buy several other items is called a "loss leader".

> Supermarkets offer gasoline price discounts as a loss-leader advertising strategy. This pushes prices down around the supermarket.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but It's not what I'm looking for. TBH I knew the phrase but I can't remember it and It's been bugging me for a while. I can't even remember what it rhymes with.

Answer (score 1):

> to cause the value of something to go higher than it's actually worth because you paid for it more because you're rich and don't care

This is often called **bidding up the price** of something.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but It's not what I'm looking for. TBH I knew the phrase but I can't remember it and It's been bugging me for a while. I can't even remember what it rhymes with.